# How do I move an app?

Tags: ios, applications, ipod-touch

I have several apps on my iPod touch (5th generation) that I would like to move from their current place on screen to a different place on screen. Is there any way to do this? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your finger on the app and hold there. The app will start wobbling and have a cross in a circle at the top left.

Then drag it to where you want. If you hit the cross it will delete the app.